# Is a static IP address set in GUI reflected in a config file?

Tags: networking, static-ip

I set a static IP address for my Ubuntu 18.04 machine using GUI and looked in several likely config files (referred to in Web tutorials) to see how the setting was reflected there and saw that it simply was not.

One example of such tutorials would be [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04/#:%7E:text=Configuring%20Static%20IP%20address%20on%20Ubuntu%20Desktop,-Setting%20up%20a&text=In%20the%20Activities%20screen%2C%20search,Click%20on%20the%20cog%20icon.&text=In%20%E2%80%9CIPV4%E2%80%9D%20Method%22%20section,IP%20address%2C%20Netmask%20and%20Gateway.).

Before I went looking further (on a potentially fruitless search), I wanted to ask:

When I set a static IP address using GUI, is that reflected in a config file somewhere?

If the answer is no, that would be highly disappointing.  The "through GUI" and the "through CLI" settings would in this case be independent and competing.  There would have to be a hierarchy among them, one overriding the other.

If the answer is yes, GUI and CLI would just be two methods at getting at the same (underlying) setting.

I hope the answer is yes and that I just haven't found the right config file yet.

If there is a way to find out the location of the relevant config file for one's particular system, please kindly include it in the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: 18.04 uses NetworkManager, no? Try `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/name-of-your-connection`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, I found 'Wired connection 1' and 'Wired connection 2' at that location, but they are both empty files (just like all the other configs mentioned in tutorials). I am using `sudo nano` and `sudo vi` to look at them. I am very new to Linux. But implicit in your comment is the statement that GUI setting should result in a text config?